# How to rotate selected element in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

so I am trying to build a small image editor in canvas, currently I have buttons that onclick will draw a specific image to the canvas (buildLayers()) then I can select any image that is on the canvas and I can move it around. My next step was to add rotation but only to selected image. Currently rotated image will appear however original one is also there... another problem is that I cannot select rotated image and when I am dragging original one, rotated image goes to a different direction eq when I move original to right, rotated moves down.

```js
function renderCanvas() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderCanvas);

    g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++) {
        drawImg(imgX[i], imgY[i], images[i]);
    }
    //draw a border on selected image
    if (numOfImages > 0) {
        drawBorder(imgX[selectedImg], imgY[selectedImg]);
        rotareImage(imgX[selectedImg], imgY[selectedImg], images[selectedImg]);
    }


}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

function drawImg(x, y, images) { 
    g.drawImage(images, x - (imgWidth / 2), y - (imgHeight / 2), imgWidth, imgHeight);
}

function buildLayers() {
    for (var layer = 0; layer < numOfImages + 1; layer++) {
        imgX[layer + numOfImages] = canvas.width / 2;
        imgY[layer + numOfImages] = canvas.height / 2;
    }
}
function rotareImage(x, y, images) {
    
    g.save();
    
    g.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    g.rotate(Math.radians(90));
    g.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);

    drawImg(x, y, images);
    g.restore();
    
}

Math.radians = function (degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
};
```

Comment: If you can see the rotated image and its default version, this is just because you told your canvas to draw default version in  the first loop call `drawImg` and then in the `rotareImage` call. `selectedImg` is probably between `0` and `numOfImages`. So if you want to draw it has the first visible layer, just filter `selectedImg` in your loop (`if(i===selectedImg){continue;}`) or if you want it to keep it's z-index call `rotareImage` inside the loop when `i === selectedImg` (`if(i === selectedImg){rotareImage(params)}else{drawImg(params)}`)

Comment: @Kaiido - Who keeps upvoting you? Your suggestion doesn't account for the fact that his `rotareImage` function is still rotating the **entire canvas.** and not just the single image layer.

Comment: @Pamblam, what do you really know about canvas drawings ? Canvas state is mutable, you can set its transform for one action (like `drawImage`) and then restore it back just before you perform some other drawings...

Comment: @Kaiido Your original comment still does not account for that. I'm also not sure that would be either easier or more efficient. Setting transform still requires an entire duplicate of the bitmap to be stored in memory.

Comment: @Pamblam no, just store the original image. You are creating endless new images for nothing... https://jsfiddle.net/9hy4v1vs/ and you can easily do the same with images : https://jsfiddle.net/9hy4v1vs/1/ ANd my original comment doesn't talks about it because it's not OP's problem. His problem is that he is drawing its image twice.

Comment: @Kaiido - i get what you're saying, but you're still storing the bitmap in memory when you transform. actually in your example you're redrawing every single image on every single frame. when you're drawing layers in a photoshop-style web-app it's much more efficient to alter the image that is already stored in memory once and just draw it as is on future renders than it is to rotate the image and re-render on every layer that is to be rotated.

Comment: also it's not endless new images. it's a single new image at a time. when the function returns the headless canvas is garbage collected. no memory is accumulated on subsequent calls.

Comment: @Pamblam, nope. You are creating new images, I'm not. Ok for layer style but only when needed (i.e if there were a non updating background + central set of objects + non-moving foreground). Here, you're not making any use of this layer, since the only thing that is updated is the rotation of the image. I am using the original image as a layer, never modify it, and just move it on the main context like you would do with a layer on e.g Illustrator.

Comment: And yes all your contexts are **marked for GC** but this means that GC will have to kick in, and thus implies that one random frame will have less time to perform everything. In my implementation, nothing is marked for GC. And all your loaded images are polluting the memory, because browser will cache it all. This is cleared by an heavy GC, slower than anything else the browser do. Oh and nothing except the current matrix is stored anywhere when you transform the context ;-)

Comment: I had no idea browser cached dynamically generated images. I'll have to read up on that. Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to rotate only the single image instead of the whole canvas, and you have to do it before `drawImg()` is called on it.

In your **`renderCanvas`** function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfImages; i++) {

    // If this image is to be rotated/bordered
    // it needs to be done now, before drawImg() is called,
    // on the layer, not on the entire canvas
    if(i===selectedImg){

        // Draw the border
        drawBorder(imgX[i], imgY[i]);

        // Overwrite the Image object with the rotated version
        imgX[i] = rotateLayer(imgX[i], 90); // 90 degree rotation
    }

    // Now add it to the canvas
    drawImg(imgX[i], imgY[i], images[i]);
}
```

Then create a `rotateLayer` function that will rotate the image using a headless canvas and then return the Image object.

```
function rotateLayer(img, degrees){

    // Create a headless canvas
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = img.width; c.height = img.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    // Draw the image and rotate it on the headless canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(Math.radians(degrees));

    // Get the rotated image back from the headless canvas
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = c.toDataURL();

    return image;
}
```

See the code explanation in the comments.

*Disclaimer: I just wrote this in the answer box and did not test it. It may or may not work if you simply copy and paste, it was intended to show you how to do it, not to do it for you.*

Comment: thank you, now I definitely know how to do it. I did something similar with the offscreen canvas and now I can see why it didn't work as intended. I wasted good few hours on this today, thanks again!

Comment: ouch create a new canvas at each rotate and call toDataURL and then set an image's src to this dataURL is just... 1. so slow 2. so memory consumptive 3. prone to dropped frame. At the time you call drawImage, the new content of the image may not have been loaded yet. If you're gonna make an animated rotation, that will kill your browser. You can rotate the main context only, but set the rotation anchor to the center of your image, not to your canvas' one.

Comment: @Kaiido - AFAIK there is literally no other way to do it entirely on the client side. If you've got a better answer, let's hear it! Don't be shy..

Comment: @Pamblam, what do you mean "there is literally no other way" ?  And for the answer, I'm not sure the question deserves it since the main problem is a typo I pointed to in comment to the question, and that it would take me some time that I don't have rn.

Comment: @M.Malinowski - If you're concerned about the whopping amount memory a whole canvas will have on the browser for a thousandth of a second then your only other solution is to do it on the server side.

Comment: @Pamblam you really helped me, this project is something that I do in order to learn more about canvas so your answer completely satisfy me. At this stage I am not worried about performance. thank one more time :)